# JS convert arrays into object then replace object key with property value

Tags: javascript

I need to convert an array into objects and then need to move one of object property value as a object property key name:

```
[
  {
    "description": "red",
    "type": "fruit",
    "item": "apple"
  },
  {
    "description": "yellow",
    "type":"fruit",
    "item": "banana"
  }
]
```

into

```
{
  "apple": {
    "description": "red",
    "type": "fruit"
  },
  "banana": {
    "description": "yellow",
    "type": "fruit"
  }
}
```

using `Object.assign({}, ...arr)` populates object's names into index, i need to change that index, thanks!

Comment: Just iterate over that array and place entries into a new object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` to fold your array into an object. using destructuring you can pull out the values from the object and create a new object in your desired format for the output.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "description": "red",
    "type": "fruit",
    "item": "apple"
  },
  {
    "description": "yellow",
    "type":"fruit",
    "item": "banana"
  }
]

console.log(
  data.reduce((accumulator, { item, description, type }) => ({
    ...accumulator,
    [item]: { description, type }
  }), {})
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Comment: Love that plugin!! `(:`

Comment: @Ele cheers, I wasn't happy with the stackoverflow console so made a simple one to help with presenting the results.

Comment: Some upvoted answers cuz you've shared with us that plugin!!

Comment: Cheers guys, feel free to use / fork it. it has an assertion library based on jasmine's api built in if you need it, there is examples at the bottom of the codepen, just remove the `.js` to see the pen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function **[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** to build the desired output.

```js
var array = [  {    "description": "red",    "type": "fruit",    "item": "apple"  },  {    "description": "yellow",    "type":"fruit",    "item": "banana"  }],
    result = array.reduce((a, {description, type, item}) => (Object.assign(a, {[item]: {description, type}})), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

**Unrelated:** Nice console plugin from **[@synthet1c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1733478/synthet1c)**

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with a single call to `reduce`.

```js
const data = [{
    "description": "red",
    "type": "fruit",
    "item": "apple"
  },
  {
    "description": "yellow",
    "type": "fruit",
    "item": "banana"
  }
]

const regrouped = data.reduce((acc, {
  description,
  type,
  item
}) => {
  acc[item] = {
    description,
    type
  }
  return acc
}, {});

console.log(regrouped)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is using a `forEach` on the array and build an object based on the properties:

```js
var arr = [{"description": "red", "type": "fruit", "item": "apple"},{"description":"yellow","type":"fruit","item": "banana"}]

obj = {};
arr.forEach((o) => {
    obj[o.item] = o;
    delete o.item;
});

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have covered the vanilla JS solution quite well, but if you can use lodash, you can do this by combining the methods `keyBy`, `mapValues`, and `omit` to produce a nice one-liner:

```js
const myArray = [{
  "description": "red",
  "type": "fruit",
  "item": "apple"
}, {
  "description": "yellow",
  "type": "fruit",
  "item": "banana"
}];

const result = _.mapValues(_.keyBy(myArray, o => o.item), o => _.omit(o, "item"));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce

```js
let arr=[
  {
    "description": "red",
    "type": "fruit",
    "item": "apple"
  },
  {
    "description": "yellow",
    "type":"fruit",
    "item": "banana"
  }
]
const convert_to_object = (myarray) =>
   myarray.reduce((o, i) => {
     o[i.item] = {description:i.description,type:i.type}
     return o
   }, {})
const peopleObject = convert_to_object(arr)
console.log(peopleObject)
```